# How to create a zip file from contents of a folder with certain name pattern?

Tags: command-line, bash, tar, gzip

is it possible to create a `tar.gz` file from contents of a folder but only put the files with certain name pattern in the archive and ignore the rest? for example just put the files which their names are *log_*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `tar` directly:

```
tar -zcvf file.tar.gz log_*
```

Comment: it seems to be simplest way

Answer (score 12):

Example Using zip(you can choose any other compression tool instead):

```
find /path-to-dir -name 'log_*' | zip archive.zip -@
```

example:

```
$ ls
file  log_1  log_2  log_3
```

Now zip all files log_* in zipped called archive.zip

```
$ find . -name 'log_*' | zip archive.zip -@
  adding: log_1 (stored 0%)
  adding: log_3 (stored 0%)
  adding: log_2 (stored 0%)
```

Now let's check output:

```
$ ls
archive.zip  file  log_1  log_2  log_3
```

Comment: Note that this search is recursive into subdirectories. The folder structure is kept in the compressed output file, but containing only files that matched the search query (eg. log_1, log_2, folder/log_21, folder/folder/log_31....)